# Elasticsearch Multiple field aggregation with field wise document count

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

In a scenario, I have to search for phone numbers and license numbers that start with '***861***'. I need to get field-wise matching data and field-wise total document count.

For that, I used multiple field aggregation.

In the output, I can see the field-wise data. But I also want to see the field-wise total count. Below is the search and aggregation query.

**My Query:**

```
GET emp_details_new/_search 
{
   "_source": [],
   "size": 0,
   "min_score": 1,
   "query": {
      "multi_match": {
        "query": "861",
         "fields": ["licence_num","phone"],
         "type": "phrase_prefix"
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "licence_num": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "licence_num.keyword",
            "include": "86.*"
         }
      },
      "phone": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "phone.keyword",
            "include": "86.*"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Output:**
In the output, I can get only field wise data, also looking for field-wise count.

```
{
  "took" : 31,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "phone" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "8613789726",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "8617323318",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "licence_num" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "8616203799",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "8616829169",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Value Count aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) for field-wise total count.

```json
{
    "_source": [],
    "size": 0,
    "min_score": 1,
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "861",
            "fields": [
                "licence_num",
                "phone"
            ],
            "type": "phrase_prefix"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "licence_num": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "licence_num.keyword",
                "include": "86.*"
            }
        },
        "phone": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "phone.keyword",
                "include": "86.*"
            }
        },
        "licence_num_count": {
            "value_count": {
                "field": "licence_num.keyword"
            }
        },
        "phone_count": {
            "value_count": {
                "field": "phone.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For licence_num_count and phone_count, I am getting 4. It is supposed to be 2 for each. But here it gives the total hits count for licence_num_count and phone_count which is wrong.

Comment: This works, but my phone field data contains a dash '-'. The query matches a phone number that starts with '86x-xxx-xxxx' and also matches the phone number containing '321-860-xxxx'. The second phone number should not consider. What changes do I need to do to exclude the second phone number matching '86' in between?

Comment: This is happening because your number is tokenized by standard tokenizer and it split number on dash. You can define your custom tokenizer and configured it for `phone` field so it will resolved this issue. Please check [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/searching-for-exactly-a-hyphenated-word/161216/2) answer.